# javascript: download page in background and "clean" javascript context

Tags: javascript

I have a specific scenario: I'm using a js library which is adding it's properties to the window object (and does a lot of stuff in the global context). According to their documentation this library needs to be initialized in the title tag.

My use case is to replace the whole page with a new one containing different settings for this library in background:

1. Load start page with this library
2. Some event occurs -> download the new page
3. Replace the start page with the new page. The important thing here is to fully reset javascript context like the page was reloaded.

I tried to use document.write function:

```
// let html = downloaded html
document.open();
document.write(html);
document.close();
```

But it seems that the javascript objects of this library initiated on the start page load are still there  and the library throws errors.

So I need fully reset the start page without actually reloading it. Is this even possible?

Comment: Which type of library do you use? You should use a library like, for example, react that does all you need out of the box

Comment: nono, I'm using plain js and the library I'm referring to is AFrame. I didn't find a way to completely restart an "environment" in their API, so thought I can download a new page in background.